# Sample Codes to Retore Color of ListView after orientation changed

Tags: android, android-listview

I would like to know some codes on how to restore the `Color` of `ListView` after orientation changed. From landscape to potrait and vice versa. 
 Thank you.

Comment: can you please explain more detailed what are you trying to achieve, what colors are you talking about?

Comment: Hi Android-Developer. For example. I use listView for menu tabs. so to differentiate between the tab that has been clicked/touched, I use different color. However, if I can change the orientation, from landscape to portrait, the color can not be restored/remained. It became the original one before been touched/clicked.

Comment: so as i understand you have listview where you want to save the selected item position after changing to landscape mode, is that rght?

Answer (score 0):

I m not sure i understood what you want to achive but if i get it right you have a `ListView` and you want to color every item with different color.

There are several way of doing this, one and the simplest is to handle the configuration change by yourself by defing the `Activity` with this:

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|keyboard|smallestScreenSize|screenSize"
```

your `Activity` won't be recreated on all this events and it will just resize your view without loosing the state. Be carefull this has lots of down sides depending on what you are doing in your `Activity`/`Fragment`.

An other solution is to keep track of the state of every `ListView` item by yourself, so, for instance make an int array and save there the color of all your list view elements and use it to color the view in your adatper `getView()` call.

Comment: Hi jimpanzer. Let me explain a little further. I want to save the selected item position in listView after changing to landscape portrait mode. :)

Comment: so instead of using an integer, use a boolean array that holds the selected state for every item an save it across avtivity instances with the onSaveInstanceState()/onRestoreInstanceState() patter: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/151777/saving-activity-state-in-android